# Highlight active menu items as page scrolls divs (Sidebar onscroll menu)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vu6hN/28/) by [Gaurav Kalyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3190165/gaurav-kalyan) works well in Chrome, but in Safari and Firefox it activates the wrong menu item. Instead of highlighting the menu item clicked, it highlights the menu item before. So, for example, if you click on "Punkt 4", "Punkt 3" is highlighted instead. I haven’t been able to fix this. Can someone help? I've been trying to solve this for two weeks.

HTML

```
    <section id="main">
    <div class="target" id="1">TARGET 1</div>
    <div class="target" id="2">TARGET 2</div>
    <div class="target" id="3">TARGET 3</div>
    <div class="target" id="4">TARGET 4</div>
</section>
<aside id="nav">
    <nav>
        <a href="#1" class="active">Punkt 1</a>
        <a href="#2">Punkt 2</a>
        <a href="#3">Punkt 3</a>
        <a href="#4">Punkt 4</a>
    </nav>
</aside>
```

CSS

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#main {
    width: 75%;
    float: right;
}

#main div.target {
    background: #ccc;
    height: 400px;
}

#main div.target:nth-child(even) {
    background: #eee;
}

#nav {
    width: 25%;
    position: relative;
}

#nav nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 25%;
}

#nav a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav a:hover, #nav a.active {
    background: #666;
    color: #fff;
}
```

JavaScript

```
    $('#nav nav a').on('click', function(event) {
    $(this).parent().find('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.target').each(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(this).offset().top) {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#nav nav a').removeClass('active');
            $('#nav nav a[href=#'+ id +']').addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It works fine for me on Firefox 61.0 . You may need to refresh the page using `Ctrl + F5`

Comment: It's a bit deceptive @Mohamed-Yousef -- it works on the top menu item, but, for instance, if you press "Punkt 4", "Punkt 3" is highlighted. (I'm running Firefox 65.0.1 on a Mac.)

Answer (score 1):

This works fine as is if the viewport height (the inner height of the browser window) is <= 400px. That is because when you click on the `a` link in the `nav` element, with an `href` of `#4`, the default browser behavior kicks in and the element with `id="4"` is scrolled to the top (as much as is possible).

When the viewport is the same height or smaller than the element being scrolled to, then when your `scroll` handler gets triggered, the `if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(this).offset().top)` condition evaluates as true, because the `scrollTop` will be exactly equal to the `offset().top` of the `#4` div.

However, when the viewport is *bigger* than the content div (in your case, > 400px), when the browser tries to scroll the last div into view, it can completely do so whilst still displaying part of the bottom half of the previous div. Which means that the 3rd div will pass your scroll handler `if` check, not your fourth. (The offset top of the last div will not be <= the scrollTop of the window).

[image: example of viewport height more than 400 pixels]

### So what's the solution?

I would make it so that each target div is at least the same height as the viewport. You can achieve this on modern browsers using `min-height: 100vh;` (100% of the viewport height). That means when the last one is scrolled into view, it will completely fill the viewport, and the correct div will pass your `scroll` logic check correctly.

[See here for a working fork.](http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/p2o4976m/)

### Bonus tip

There is a number of things you can do to improve performance of this code. Cache the creation of jQuery variables, avoid the repeated work happening 4 times on every scroll event (which can happen very often), etc. It works okay for now, but it may become a bottleneck later.

Comment: Thanks you so much for these pointers @GregL. I’ve tried incorporating “min-height: 100vh” in a [project](https://raydouglas.co.uk/Test/Proper/Another.html) I’ve been working on (with a smooth scroll). While “min-height:100vh” has fixed the most immediate problems, I’ve run into further issues in Safari and on mobile browsers.

Thank you so much for your help, though. Much appreciated.

Comment: For non jquery code, use `window.scrollY > elm.offsetTop` and I like to subtract a value to adjust for not beign right at the top. If you wanna subtract half screen height then: `if (window.scrollY >= elm.offsetTop - window.innerHeight / 2)`